> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (18) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (1.8)
As of other available questions, i have tried all the solutions but doesn't work.
Execution failed for task ':domain:compileDebugKotlin'.

Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (18) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (1.8).

It occurs only in my domain module though
plugins {
    `kotlin-android`
    `android-library`
    id ("io.realm.kotlin")
}

apply<MainGradlePlugin>()

android {
    namespace = "com.example.domain"
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(21)
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    compose()
    realm()
}

Dependency handler class
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.project

object Dependencies {
    val composeDependency = listOf(
        "androidx.compose.material3:material3:${Versions.composeMaterial3}",
        "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.compose.ui:ui-android:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview-android:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:${Versions.composeCompiler}",
        "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:${Versions.navigation}",
        "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core-android:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended-android:${Versions.compose}",
        "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:${Versions.lifecycle}",
        "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.31.0-alpha",
        "androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.4",
        "androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.6.4"
    )

    val realm = listOf(
        "io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.11.0",
        "io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.11.0",
        "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.0",
    )

    val retrofitDependency = listOf(
        "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${Versions.okHttp}",
        "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${Versions.okHttp}",
        "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${Versions.retrofit}",
        "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:${Versions.retrofit}",
    )


    val koinDependencies = listOf(
        "io.insert-koin:koin-android:${Versions.koin}",
        "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:${Versions.koin}",
        "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:${Versions.koin}",
        "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-navigation:${Versions.koin}",
        "io.insert-koin:koin-core:${Versions.koin}",

        )

    val coilDependency = listOf(
        "io.coil-kt:coil:${Versions.coil}",
        "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:${Versions.coil}"
    )

    val random: List<String> = listOf(
        "com.ehsanmsz:msz-progress-indicator:0.8.0",
    )
}

fun DependencyHandler.retrofit() {
    Dependencies.retrofitDependency.forEach { dependency ->
        implementation(dependency)
    }
}

fun DependencyHandler.compose() {
    Dependencies.composeDependency.forEach { dependency ->
        implementation(dependency)
    }
}

fun DependencyHandler.koin() {
    Dependencies.koinDependencies.forEach { dependency ->
        implementation(dependency)
    }
}

fun DependencyHandler.coil() {
    Dependencies.coilDependency.forEach { dependency ->
        implementation(dependency)
    }
}

fun DependencyHandler.presentation() {
    implementation(project(":presentation"))
}

fun DependencyHandler.network() {
    implementation(project(":network"))
}

fun DependencyHandler.di() {
    implementation(project(":di"))
}

fun DependencyHandler.domain() {
    implementation(project(":domain"))
}

fun DependencyHandler.data() {
    implementation(project(":data"))
}

fun DependencyHandler.core() {
    implementation(project(":core"))
}

fun DependencyHandler.random() {
    Dependencies.random.forEach { dependency ->
        implementation(dependency)
    }
}

fun DependencyHandler.realm() {
    Dependencies.realm.forEach { dependency ->
        implementation(dependency)
    }
}

Main Gradle plugin
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension
import org.gradle.api.JavaVersion
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.dependencies

class MainGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        applyPlugin(target)
        applySetProjectConfig(target)
        with(target) {
            plugins.all {
                dependencies {
                    add("implementation", "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-android:1.6.4")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun applyPlugin(project: Project) {
        project.apply {
            plugin("android-library")
            plugin("kotlin-android")
        }
    }

    private fun applySetProjectConfig(project: Project) {
        project.android().apply {
            compileSdk = ProjectConfig.compileSdk
            defaultConfig {
                minSdk = ProjectConfig.minSdk
                testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
            }
            buildFeatures.compose = true
            composeOptions.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.11"
        }
    }

    private fun Project.android() = extensions.getByType(LibraryExtension::class.java)
}


Found any solution?
